# Return boolean result from getmapping using jparepository

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

```
This is my getmapping controller
@GetMapping("/email")
    public List<user> doesUsernameExists(@RequestParam String username) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("Inside doesUsernameExists");        
        return this.usernameExists.findByUsername(username);
    }
This is my JpaRepository interface
@Repository
public interface usernameExists extends JpaRepository<user, Long>{  
    List<user> findByUsername(String userName); 
}
```

This code is working fine but it is giving response in json with id username and password.But,
I want to return true if username exists in db table otherwise false what should I do please help .

Comment: Return a boolean then instead of the list. Rewrite your method to `boolean existsByUsername` in Spring Data JPA (as explained in the documentation).

Comment: Consider adding the solution as an answer and accept it so that your question can be closed. Thanks!

Comment: How to add solution as an answer ? Can you please tell I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Just write it below, in the `Your Answer` section.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Repository
public interface usernameExists extends JpaRepository<user, Long>{
    
    boolean existsByUsername(String userName);
    
}

@Autowired
    private usernameExists usernameExists;
    
    @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
    @GetMapping("/email")
    public boolean doesUsernameExists(@RequestParam String username) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        System.out.println("Inside doesUsernameExists");
        
        return this.usernameExists.existsByUsername(username);
    }
```

this solved the problem

Comment: When you answering you need to explain what exactly you do to solve the problem